# iOS - crash when orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, exc-bad-access

I am at the final part of my project and I spread adHoc version for my mates.

I get this error at the `Organizer` `Device Logs:

```
Thread 24 Crashed:
0   MakoTV2                         0x004e39a0 CDownloadPartsStep::State::StopDownload() + 288
1   MakoTV2                         0x005385d6 CDownloadPartsStep::State::~State() + 122
2   MakoTV2                         0x00537794 CP2PDownloadStep::State::~State() + 80
3   MakoTV2                         0x0051cb62 std::tr1::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() + 50
4   MakoTV2                         0x004e3d24 CDownloadPartsStep::Execute(CDownloadContext&) const + 544
5   MakoTV2                         0x00587e36 IWorkItem::ExecuteFromQueue(std::tr1::shared_ptr<void> const&) + 30
6   MakoTV2                         0x00587164 CWorkQueue::CWorkThreadPoolTarget::ThreadFunction() + 412
7   MakoTV2                         0x0032b0d2 ACE_Task_Base::svc_run(void*) (Task.cpp:271)
8   MakoTV2                         0x0032be28 ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke_i() (Thread_Adapter.cpp:161)
9   MakoTV2                         0x0032bf4e ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke() (Thread_Adapter.cpp:96)
10  MakoTV2                         0x002f6914 ace_thread_adapter (Base_Thread_Adapter.cpp:122)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b399c1a _pthread_body + 138
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b399b8a _pthread_start + 98
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b397c8c thread_start + 4
```

It's happened when I watch video in landscape -> go to background -> coming back to the app (become active) and continue watching the video from the exact same point -> change orientation to portrait to landscape and vice versa (more then one time).

In `Orginizer` -> `Console` I get this:

```
<Error>: 17:10:31.185 [0x4770000] sessionID = 0x2e523: cannot get ClientInfo
<Error>: 17:10:31.187 ERROR:     [0x4770000] 150: AudioQueue: Error 'ini?' from AudioSessionSetClientPlayState(0x2e523)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Seems like a download issue rather than orientation issue. You need to elaborate more about how do you load the video.

Comment: Please see my edit question (at the bottom of the question), 10x!

Comment: Does this bug happen if you don't change the orientaion after returning from background?

Comment: Are you handling your audio queue while entering in to the background?